# How to make UITableView look like the one in Contacts?

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to make `UITableViewController` look like following.
(it has picture and several rows for someone's identify.)

I wonder how to make like following programmatically.

How to adjust `UITableViewCell`'s origin.x and width? 
How to add a picture at left top?

Please help me..  I will thank you.

[image]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];

    cell.frame = CGRectMake(50, 0, 250, 44) <--- ?????? I think this is wrong way.

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best bet is that either there are two static `UITableViews` inside a `UIScrollView` or that it's some custom subclass `UIView` set as `tableHeaderView` and styled to look as on the picture.  If I were to implement it I'd go with the second choice.

Answer (score 0):

Make a subclass of `UITableView`.  Give your subclass properties referring to the photo well and the three special row cells.

Override `layoutSubviews` to call `[super layoutSubviews]` and then set the frames of the photo well and the three special row cells.

The photo well should not be a cell.